# How to separate errors and warnings in vuelidate

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Is it possible to separate errors and warnings in vuelidate?

I have some setup with vuelidate (option API) and vue.js 2 and I want to use different validators for either error validation or optional warning validation. The invalid warning validators should not count to $v.$error but has to be detected somehow.

Here is some example code:

```vuejs
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="$v.field1.required" class="error">This is required</div>
    <div v-if="$v.field1.greaterThan" class="warn">Value should be greather than 10</div>
    <input @click="$v.$touch" v-model="field1" type="number">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

const greaterThan = (params) => (value) => value > params;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      field1: 0
    }
  },
  validations() {
    return {
      field1: {
        required, // this should be a error validator
        greatherThan: greaterThan(10) // this should be a warning validator
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Probably https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-props-support .

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks! I'll give it a try. But how can that prevent $v.$error to change when greaterThan triggers?

Comment: You can't, you need to compute error and warn state on your own based on field states. With next Vuelidate version and composition API you could have 2 validators for that.